# Hibernate: NaturalId with inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, hibernate-onetomany, natural-key

I have following Entities (short version):

GroupOfStudents:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_of_students")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AGroupOfStudents extends AModel {
}
```

Centuria:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cohort")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Cohort extends AGroupOfStudents {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    // @NaturalId <- here is the problem
    private int number;
}
```

Cohort:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "centuria")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Centuria extends AGroupOfStudents {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    // @NaturalId <- here is the problem
    private int cohort;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    // @NaturalId <- here is the problem
    private char maniple;
}
```

So I have a CourseLecture with a GroupOfStudents. There are different GroupOfStudents like Centuria or Cohort. But I want the number field of the Cohort to be a NaturalId. this will cause the error:

```
AnnotationException: @NaturalId only valid on root entity (or its @MappedSuperclasses)
```

but why can I use @NaturalId only on root entities? How can I solve this problem without breaking up my class inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ,I totally misunderstood `@NaturalId`, the main purpose is to enable queries by this NaturalIds on the table, so this working only on root entities makes sense.

what a wanted was a simple unique constraint for my sub entities, this can be achieved by:

`@Column(unique = true)` for a single column

`@Table(name = "centuria", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "cohort", "maniple", "letter" }) })` for multiple columns